# Different meanings of "homo"

Tags: etymology

"Homo" has two main meanings that I am aware of: "man" (e.g. "homo sapiens"), and "same" (e.g. "homogenous", "homosexual", etc.).

Those seem like pretty distinct meanings, but I am curious to know if their etymology has a common ancestor at some point.  Basically, how did "homo" come to have these two very distinct meanings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311168/root-word-homo-in-homosexual-is-there-a-word-like-misandry-specifically-for-gay) - at least [the answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/311173/116151) can be found there: it's Latin vs. Greek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Homosexual" [derives](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=homosexual&allowed_in_frame=0) from Greek, where "homo" means "same." It's similar to the word "homogeneous."

"Homo sapiens" [derives](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Homo%20sapiens&allowed_in_frame=0) from Latin, where "homo" means "man." It's similar to the Spanish word "hombre," and the oft-quoted scriptural passage "Ecce homo."

Comment: Thanks for the links to etymology online.  Didn't realize that it existed.